# How to navigate to a route without routerLink in angular2

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I am working with [nebular](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/getting-started/what-is-nebular) framework, from the amazing guys at [akveo](https://www.akveo.com/).

One of the components is a [context menu](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/context-menu/overview#nbcontextmenudirective) that creates a popup menu with it's options read from an array

```
items = [{ title: 'Profile' }, { title: 'Log out' }];
```

I want to navigate to a different screen but tutorials talk mostly about `routerLink`

```
<p>This is my link <a routerLink="/getMeOut">out</a></p>
```

But in this case, I can't add a `<a>` tag because they abstracted the click event and allow you to subscribe like

```
this.menuService.onItemClick()
  .pipe(
    filter(({ tag }) => tag === 'my-context-menu'),
    map(({ item: { title } }) => title),
  )
  .subscribe(title => {
    console.error(`${title} was clicked!`)
  });
```

And that prints when each button was clicked, but I have to trigger the navigation inside the `.subscribe()` function.

How to do so?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the outer route has got to exist, in some routing.module

```
// app-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'getMeOut', component: OutComponent },
  ..
]
```

Four things are needed then

1. Import Router from `@angular/router`.
2. Create a private router in your constructor `private router: Router`.
3. Call `navigateByUrl()` with the desired route.
4. Identify your context menu with the `nbContextMenuTag` property.

Then, in the module that holds the context menu, we create the router to handle the navigation like

```
// awesome.component.ts
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { NbMenuService } from '@nebular/theme';

@Component({
  selector: 'awesome',
  styleUrls: ['./awesome.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './awesome.component.html',
})

ngOnInit() {
  this.menuService.onItemClick()
  .pipe(
    filter(({ tag }) => tag === 'my-context-menu'),
    map(({ item: { title } }) => title),
  )
  .subscribe(title => {
    if (title === 'Log out') this.router.navigateByUrl('/getMeOut');
    console.error(`${title} was clicked!`)
  });
}

constructor(
  private menuService: NbMenuService,
  private router: Router) {
}
```

See the simple use of [navigateByUrl](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigatebyurl) from `@angular/router`.

Just add `nbContextMenuTag="my-context-menu"` to the html template

```
<nb-action *nbIsGranted="['view', 'user']" >
 <nb-user nbContextMenuTag="my-context-menu"></nb-user>
</nb-action>
```

I hope it's not a dupe. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432407/how-to-navigate-to-a-specific-part-of-the-page-with-the-angular-2-router) answer but it meant more about nested routers.

Comment: This barely works. Once I want to go back, it doesn't recognize the rest of the routes. I think what I need is access to the original router